# Storing a module as a variable in rust

Tags: rust

I have 2 different modules with precisely the same implementation, same functions, types, etc. They just do different things. I would like to be able to choose one of these modules at runtime and use it exclusively. Furthermore, there are several of these modules that may or may not exist at compile-time based on platform, features, etc. [this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=5eaf67fd25855b8ffcef040b8bb16ec6) is a link to a super stripped-down version of what I want. I am trying to choose between the various [gfx-hal](https://docs.rs/gfx-hal/0.4.0/gfx_hal) backends. The best I have been able to come up with is a macro that creates an if statement for each possible module then fires that if statement whenever a function in a module is run. However, this doesn't really seem elegant or at all good. So is there a way to store the modules in a variable and access it, or some way to do this that mimics that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you mean something akin to `#[cfg(os)]` constraints on modules? Take for example [`std::os`'s implementation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/src/std/os/mod.rs.html#41-56) which declares modules depending on the OS. Naming the modules the same name would effectively make them a compile-time switch case.

Comment: Unfortunately I am required to make that choice at run-time. Otherwise this would be quite a bit easier :)

Comment: Then why not have a trait which summarizes the module, including the name of it, functions, types, etc. and implement it for a unit struct. This will be similar to [`gfx-rs`'s `Backend` trait](https://docs.rs/gfx-hal/0.4.0/gfx_hal/trait.Backend.html). Note that you will need to have generic functions everywhere. [Here is an example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=84295b481fb966733eef2e20fac58c85).

Comment: coincidentally I am trying to switch between gfx-hal's various backends, I completely blanked and forgot to put that in the original question

Comment: Ah, then my suggestion will be to have some kind of `enum` describing the various types you could have or a single entrypoint function which initializes based on a generic. In the example I gave in my edit to my previous comment, the `print_module` function would be the entrypoint function.

Comment: Yep that looks like exactly what I was looking for. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this by turning each of your modules into its own trait implementation, similar to how [`gfx-rs`](https://docs.rs/gfx-hal/0.4.0/gfx_hal/trait.Backend.html) does things.

Your "`trait`" would in actuality never be implemented with state, and instead be a collection of associated items like functions, other types, etc.

You could package it up like [so](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d7af97b523217a03cba9ca9444935aa2):

```
#![allow(dead_code)]
mod foo {
    pub fn print() { println!("hello from foo") }
}

mod bar {
    pub fn print() { println!("hello from bar"); }
}

mod zam { // this may not exist depending on the platform, one will always exist
    pub fn print() { println!("hello from zam"); }
}

struct FOO;
struct BAR;
struct ZAM;

trait RuntimeModule {
    fn print();
}

impl RuntimeModule for FOO {
    fn print() { foo::print(); }
}

impl RuntimeModule for BAR {
    fn print() { bar::print(); }
}

impl RuntimeModule for ZAM {
    fn print() { zam::print(); }
}

fn main() {
    // Here we decide which to use
    print_module::<FOO>();
}
// This is our "entrypoint"
fn print_module<T: RuntimeModule>() {
    T::print();
}
```

If we decide which to use at runtime (in this case in `main`), we can then call a generic function which will use the associated types/functions to make decisions.

Note that **you would not be able to use `Box<dyn RuntimeModule>`** if `RuntimeModule` contained associated types that were different for each implementation.